# Having trouble centering my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, center

I can't get my links centered in the middle of the page. I've tried text-align: center; in just about every place I can in my style sheet to no avail.
http://www.ddofans.org/

Here the relevant code strip:

HTML:

```
<div id='nav'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>News</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Other</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#nav {
background: #035ea3;
width: auto;
text-align: middle;
}
#nav ul {

list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
zoom: 1; 
}
#nav ul:after {
content: ' ';
display: block;
font-size: 0;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
#nav ul li {
float: left;
display: block;
padding: 0;  
}
#nav ul li a {
color: #f5f5f5;
text-decoration: none;  
display: block;
padding: 15px 25px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: color .25s;
-moz-transition: color .25s;
-ms-transition: color .25s;
-o-transition: color .25s;
transition: color .25s;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
color: #000000;
}
#nav ul li a:hover:before {
width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li a:after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: -3px;
top: 19px;
height: 6px;
width: 6px;
background: #f5f5f5;
opacity: .5;
}
#nav ul li a:before {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 3px;
width: 0;
background: #000000;
-webkit-transition: width .25s;
-moz-transition: width .25s;
-ms-transition: width .25s;
-o-transition: width .25s;
transition: width .25s;
}
#nav ul li.last > a:after,
#nav ul li:last-child > a:after {
display: none;
}
#nav ul li.active a {
color: #000000;
}
#nav ul li.active a:before {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: text-align:middle should be `text-align:center` and instead of floating your li, make them `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#nav {
   background: #035ea3;
   width: auto;
   text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   line-height: 1;
   display: inline-block;
   zoom: 1; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: inline-block;` to `#nav ul` & `text-align:center` to `#nav`
You are currently using `text-align:middle` in `#nav` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap you nav in a container and then make your navbar center by specifying a margin.

your nav style should be:

```
#nav {
background: #035EA3;
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and your html would look something like this:

```
<div style="width: 100%;background-color: #035EA3;">
<div id="nav">

<ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span>News</span></a></li>
   <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Other</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/tY6aN/)

Change `text-align: middle;` to `text-align: center;` of #nav &

`display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` of `#nav ul`